# PHP - getElementsByTagName('rsslink') results inconsistent RSS feeds

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

I am trying to capture useful RSS feeds from different journals using getElementsByTagName('rsslink'). The following code gets the rss feeds for LINK1 but not for LINK2. Both links show similar xml pages when opened in a browser. I cannot figure out why the code does not capture the feeds for LINK2.

```
<?php
      //$journalLink = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/rss/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1944-7973'; //LINK 1
      $journalLink = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/feed/2199160x/most-recent'; // LINK 2
      
      $rss = new DOMDocument();
      $rss->load($journalLink);
      $feed = array();
      foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
          $item = array (
              'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
              'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
              'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
          );
          array_push($feed, $item);
      } //foreach 
      $noRSSItem  = count($feed);
      echo "noRSSItem: $noRSSItem  <br/>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting into the loop? Add some echo debugging and see how far you are getting. Rule out the obvious stuff because SO is a terrible debugger.

Comment: Thanks @clvrmnky. I am not getting into the loop. The array returns a null array. I used the code of ThW.

Answer (score 0):

`The second url uses the Atom namespace for the item link element.
Atom allows for multiple links with different relations and types.

The easiest way is to use Xpath expressions.

```php
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($journalLink);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register a prefix for the Atom namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

// xpath expression can include count and conditions
// check if the amount of item elements is zero
$noRSSItem = $xpath->evaluate('count(//item) = 0');

$feed = array();
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $itemNode) {
    $feed[] = [
        // fetch the content of the first title child element
        'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $itemNode),
        // same for description
        'desc' => $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $itemNode),
        // fetch the 
        'link' => $xpath->evaluate(
            'string(link|a:link[@rel="self" and @type="application/atom+xml"]/@href)', 
            $itemNode
        ),
    ];
}

var_dump($feed);
```

#### Xpath Step By Step

- Atom 'link' child elements:
   `a:link`
- with specific attributes:
   `a:link[@rel="self" and @type="application/atom+xml"]`
- the 'href' attribute:
   `a:link[@rel="self" and @type="application/atom+xml"]/@href`
- alternativ fetch RSS (no namespace) `link` child elements:
   `link|a:link[@rel="self" and @type="application/atom+xml"]/@href`
- Cast to string:
   `string(link|a:link[@rel="self" and @type="application/atom+xml"]/@href)`

Comment: Thanks @ThW but the output array of your code for urls with the Atom namespace returns a null array. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Demo: https://3v4l.org/53C8F#v8.1.6